# Hibernate Spring JPA javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-orm

I try to save User using hibernate method persist.
After i run my test method i get an exception. I checked many topics with the same problem, such as add @Transactional to the class, checked spring versions etc.  But it still have this exception

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.merge(Unknown Source)
at ua.javagym.repository.jpa.JpaUserRepositoryImpl.save(JpaUserRepositoryImpl.java:28)
at ua.javagym.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:23)
at ua.javagym.service.UserServiceImplTest.testSave(UserServiceImplTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

UserServiceImplTest

```
@ContextConfiguration({
    "classpath:spring/spring-app.xml",
    "classpath:spring/spring-db.xml",
    "classpath:spring/spring-tools.xml"
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
protected UserService userService;

@Test
public void testSave() throws Exception {
    User user = new User("Usertest", "userMail", "user", new Date(), Role.USER);
    userService.save(user);
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

public User save(User user) {
    return repository.save(user);
}
```

JpaUserRepositoryImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JpaUserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


@Override
@Transactional
public User save(User user) {
    if (!user.isNew()){
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }else entityManager.merge(user);
    return user;
}
}
```

Spring-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:annotation-config/> <!--подключаем использование аннотаций-->
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.javagym.**.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.javagym.**.web"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.javagym.**.repository.jpa"/>


</beans>
```

Spring-db.xml

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/mysql/mySQL.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:packagesToScan="ua.javagym.model">

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
            <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}" value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
              p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gym</groupId>
<artifactId>gym</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spring.test>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.test>
    <spring.jdbc>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.jdbc>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.orm>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.orm>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.validator>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator>
    <ehcache.version>2.10.1</ehcache.version>

</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> <!--реализация API slf4j-->
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.test}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.jdbc}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.orm}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = User.DELETE, query = "delete from User u where u.id=:id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = User.GET_ALL, query = "select u from User u")
})
public class User extends NamedEntity{
public static final String DELETE = "User.delete";
public static final String GET_ALL = "User.getAlL";

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled = true;

@Column(name = "registered")
private Date registered = new Date();

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Role role;

public User() {
}

public User(String name, String email, String password, Date registered, Role role) {
    super(name);
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.registered = registered;
    this.role = role;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added [@EnableTransactionManagement](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) to your configuration?

Comment: your advice was very helpful!
now it works, thank you!

Comment: I watched a lot of tutorials and there was nothing about this annotation. I am new in jpa, can you explain me in a few words why it does`t work without it?

Comment: Hi, there are two configuration approaches in setting up spring data: annotation based and xml based.

Comment: I personally prefer the annotation based version. The reason is that without this annotation the transaction manager bean is not available (spring doesn't inject it). I'm sure there is a way to set it up via xml based approach but I haven't tried it.
Take a look to this documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/